# htmlentities() returns empty values despite UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

So I'm trying to escape a string in PHP using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).
Problem is, htmlentities returns an empty string.

I'm receiving this string through an html `<form>`. The page containing the form tag has the following meta tag : `<meta charset="utf-8">`

My string is encoded in UTF-8, `htmlentites()` third parameters is `'UTF-8'` and I still get an empty string.

Here is my code :

```
$str = strtolower(trim($str));
var_dump($str, mb_detect_encoding($str), htmlentities($str), htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1'));
```

And here is what var_dump displays :

```
// Original string is é-è
// Expected output is &eacute;-&egrave;
string '�-�' (length=5) // Original string but why is the length 5 ?
string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
string '&atilde;&copy;-&atilde;&uml;' (length=28) // WTF ??
```

Anyone know where it's coming from ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what was wrong.
`strtolower` is causing the problem.
**Please use [`mb_strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-strtolower.php)**

```
var_dump($str, mb_detect_encoding($str), htmlentities($str), htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1'));
$str = trim($str);
var_dump($str, mb_detect_encoding($str), htmlentities($str), htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1'));
$str = strtolower($str);
var_dump($str, mb_detect_encoding($str), htmlentities($str), htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1'));
```

Here is the output :

```
// raw string é-è
string 'é-è' (length=5)
string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
string '&eacute;-&egrave;' (length=17)
string '&eacute;-&egrave;' (length=17)
string '&Atilde;&copy;-&Atilde;&uml;' (length=28)
// trim('é-è')
string 'é-è' (length=5)
string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
string '&eacute;-&egrave;' (length=17)
string '&eacute;-&egrave;' (length=17)
string '&Atilde;&copy;-&Atilde;&uml;' (length=28)
// strtolower('é-è')
string '�-�' (length=5)
string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
string '&atilde;&copy;-&atilde;&uml;' (length=28)
```

Somehow, `strtolower()` seems to work only in 'ISO-8859-1', and as you can see in the var_dumps, it transforms `&Atilde;` into `&atilde;`

Comment: Did you post this question to answer by yourself ?

Comment: @SaadSuri Found the answer right before posting (or going mad) and decided to post the answer. Maybe it'll help someone.